# Open source LWC/ React LDS for Appexchange product

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Instead of LWC/Aura can I use [Open Source LWC](https://lwc.dev/) or [LDS React](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/) to build Appexchange products?
My thought process is If I use open source LWC I can deploy the same app to another platform like [google workspace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace), [Chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions), or host on websites.

Comment: Can you try to add little more information like what is the use case. Which functionality you think will not be implemented using lwc for your appexchange product?

Comment: added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use Open Source LWC or LDS React to build Appexchange products?

Yes, you can. You may want to do some experiments to see which one is easier to work with (LWC vs React), and/or go with whatever you feel more comfortable using. People will want to go on about which is better, but most of that is subjective and opinionated. Go with whatever you feel is the better option. React and LWC both work, with some limitations either way, in Salesforce and off-platform. From a technical perspective, your choice of framework will not prevent you from passing Security Reviews or getting listed on the AppExchange, so you can use whichever you feel has the best characteristics.